# how to hide capture button and cancel button in camara?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing game application.In which i have set UIView on camara overly.When i start application then its working properly but cancel and capture button is shown.I want to hide this button.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set UIImagePickerController `showsCameraControls` property to NO.